# Pyinstaller --windowed or --noconsole .exe not allowing chromedriver to open

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I have a python program that I am converting to a .exe file. I have compiled with Pyinstaller and all is working fine. I now want to get rid of the console window as I have a pyqt user interface. I have tried:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed --icon=favicon.ico main.py
```

Its compiling fine and running however when chromedriver is activated it doesnt show up. It works fine when i do not use --windowed or --noconsole.

Anyone had this problem before?

Thanks
Jamie

Answer (score 10):

I know that this question has been since 2016, but I would like to share my knowledge.

Try to put `--noconsole` before `--onefile`.

So, the command will be:

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --onefile --windowed --icon=favicon.ico main.py
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.7 use subprocess like this:

```
DEVNULL = open(os.devnull,"wb")
output = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True,stderr=DEVNULL,stdin=DEVNULL)
```

In Python 3 use subprocess like this:

```
DEVNULL = subprocess.DEVNULL
output=subprocess.check_output(command,shell=True, stderr = DEVNULL , stdin = DEVNULL )
```

Hopefully it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

add  `--noconsole` flag to your script call and remove `--windowed`, I tested this and it worked for me.

this would be :

```
pyinstaller --noconsole --icon=favicon.ico main.py
```

Comment: I tried --noconsole and it still was failing to bring up selenium. I will try again without the --onefile and see if that works. Cheers

Comment: can you describe your environment, python version, os etc.. ?

Comment: Hi, using python 3.4 on windows. I believe its the --onefile that is creating the program. Tried --windowed and --noconsole without the --onefile and that seems to work. Only problem is that when chromedriver launches now it includes a console popup. not sure if there is anyway to get rid of that

Comment: There is a workaround to hide chromedriver console that implies modifying the driver itself in Python, I did not try it myself, you can look at it in this post  (2nd answer): [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Change the extension of your main (GUI) file.
From: `*.py to *.pyw`
(Python officially supported).

Then:
`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole main.pyw`

This worked for me.

**From [pyinstaller.org](https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/operating-mode.html#using-a-console-window):**

> for Windows a file extension of .pyw suppresses the console window that normally appears. Likewise, a console window will not be provided when using a myscript.pyw script with PyInstaller.