# Is there any solutions to close cmd window when run a .exe file?

Tags: exe, pyinstaller

I have a .exe file in my application that is converted from .py file through pyinstaller. When I run that .exe file, there shows a cmd window. And what I want is to close that window.
Can everyone give me a solutions?
Thanh you.

Comment: Use the [`--windowed` option](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options) to not provide a command-line prompt.

Comment: @MaximeLaunois Thank you for your answer, actually I use the following command:

Comment: @MaximeLaunois : pyinstaller --onefile --noupx --windowed --add-binary "chromedriver.exe;." --icon=ac_solution.ico bot.py, I tried your solution and the console of "bot.exe" file has been closed, but there is still a console of "chromedriver.exe" file. Can you help me close that console? Thank you very much

Comment: Maybe this answer will help you to get rid of the `chromedriver.exe` console: [Getting rid of chromedirver console window with pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52644136/10875622)

Comment: @MaximeLaunois Great, thank you very much