# selenium hide chromdriver console window

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I have created a program with python where I am using selenium. I also created a .exe with pyinstaller. If I run the .exe chrome opens normally. But for some reason, the console appears too. This only happens if I am launching the .exe. If I launch the code in VS Code only the chrome window appears.

I found something that is written in C#:

```
var driverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

var driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, new ChromeOptions());
```

My chromdriver setup:

```
option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument("--incogneto")
chromedriver_path = driverPath
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_path)
browser.set_window_size(1100, 800)
browser.get("myurl")
```

How can I do this in Python?

Comment: Where is your python code that causes the issue?

Comment: I edit the question with my chromedriver setup

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide chromeDriver console in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the pyinstaller command, try chainging it to this: `pyinstaller ./main.py --onefile --noconsole --add-binary "chromedriver path;./driver"`

`--onefile`　It outputs as one `.exe`.

`--noconsole`　The console is not displayed when the created exe is executed.

`--add-binary`　Specify the binary file you want to add to the exe. The specification method is `"source_file_path; destination_file_path"`. In this case, we want to add the chromedriver file.

When using the `--onefile` option, the binary file specified with `--add-binary` is included in the exe. They are expanded to a temporary folder at runtime. Therefore, using relative paths in the Python source may not work.

For example, it is necessary to rewrite the part using the relative path as follows:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./driver/chromedriver.exe')
```

Rewrite as follows:

```py
import os
import sys

def resource_path(relative_path):
    try:
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(resource_path('./driver/chromedriver.exe'))
```

Add the function `resource_path` to use it.
`resource_path` gets the path with the following logic:

When executing from exe, get the relative path from sys._MEIPASS (when executing from exe, the temporary folder path is entered).

When executing from Python, get the relative path from this file (**file**).
Now it works properly whether you run it from Python or an exe file.

**IF NONE OF THAT WORKS, TRY THIS IN YOUR CODE:**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService # Similar thing for firefox also!
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW # This flag will only be available in windows

chrome_service = ChromeService('chromedriver')
chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW # We change the property in Service class, default was 0
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
```

This above code will only work on selenium version `4.0.0` or higher. If you don't have this version, try this pip command: `pip install selenium=4.0.0a7`

Then, the program works, but the chromedriver window doesn't show up!

Answer (score 3):

Selenium4 is released with this feature! No need to edit library code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService # Similar thing for firefox also!
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW # This flag will only be available in windows

# Define your own service object with the `CREATE_NO_WINDOW ` flag
# If chromedriver.exe is not in PATH, then use:
# ChromeService('/path/to/chromedriver')
chrome_service = ChromeService('chromedriver')
chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
```

Update with `pip install selenium` OR upgrade the package `pip install selenium --upgrade`

Comment: good to know. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Both answers here that change the `creationflags` field of the `Service` object don't work anymore, since the name of that field was changed to the more pythonic name of `creation_flags` (see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L65) and correspondingly [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/trunk/py/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py#L185-L204)). So in newer versions like 4.6 the exemplary code to patch in the creation flags on Windows should look like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService 
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW

chrome_service = ChromeService('chromedriver')
chrome_service.creation_flags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=chrome_service)
```

...and analogously for Firefox drivers.