# How not to show the chromewebdriver.exe window?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have gui app for parsing. After start parsing, always show chromedriver.exe window. How i can hide this window-console?

My driver:

```
options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

service = Service(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager(log_level=logging.CRITICAL).install())
        driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(
            service=service,
            options=options
        )
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Network.setUserAgentOverride', {"userAgent": UserAgent().chrome})
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get("my_url")
```

[image]

Comment: What OS are you running from (Windows?) and do you have the Developer tools window up before running Selenium?

Comment: @CodeMonkey , Yes Windows, I dont have any dev tools.

Comment: Don't recognize the Fobos Console window. It might be a custom plugin or javascript popup. If you click Settings what info does it show?

Comment: @CodeMonkey, It`s my own GUI app

Comment: Do you want that console window to be disabled/hidden or do you want the selium logging to be disabled?

Comment: @CodeMonkey, that console window to be hidden.

Comment: You should explain or show code how the chromedriver is created, presumably in your GUI app so others can re-create your setup.

Comment: @CodeMonkey, I added more code.

Comment: Does this post answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/71093078/3249399

Answer (score 0):

```
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW

service = Service(webdriver_manager.chrome.ChromeDriverManager(log_level=logging.CRITICAL).install())
service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```