# Why does the chromedriver.exe open a cmd window?

Tags: python, selenium

When I run the selenium tests with the chrome opens chromedriver.exe cmd.

How can I hide it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUcFu.png)

Comment: `chrome_options.headless = True`

Comment: No, it's not helped

Comment: I think today was already similar question.

Comment: Today queston [python - How not to show the chromewebdriver.exe window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72266305/how-not-to-show-the-chromewebdriver-exe-window) and there was link to older question [selenium - hide chromeDriver console in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python/71093078#71093078)