# How to not show the webdriver console when running an exe file created with python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, exe

I am writing a parser using the selenium library, which is launched via an exe file (converted from a python script with the --windowed parameter), but when parsing starts, the chromedriver.exe console window opens, how can I prevent it from opening?

I searched for information about this, but did not find anything normal

Answer (score 0):

After some digging, I found the answer to this question and the console no longer opened. All you need to do is add some code to the python script.

**This will only work for Windows!!**

Import the required libraries:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from subprocess import CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

I also advise you to use the [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) library, it will automatically download driver updates.
Let's import this library:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

Next, create a variable **chrome_service** and then assign a new flag to it:

```
chrome_service = ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome_service.creationflags = CREATE_NO_WINDOW
```

And already in the driver settings we specify it:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), service = chrome_service)
```

Maybe I didn’t explain very well and clearly, but everything works.
It can be said that this is a better reworked of this answer - [hide chromeDriver console in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983860/hide-chromedriver-console-in-python)

In the same place below there is essentially the same answer as I am writing here, but to close the question I answer))